# I can't see embed youtube or pdf on flutter web html viewer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-html

Can anyone help me with this please ? I'm using Flutter 3.7.9 , when I add something embeded (pdf or youtube video ) with my html editor , and then try to view it, I only can see it on mobile , doesn't show up on flutter web.
I tried using other things like easy web view but It's doesn't seem to work with these version of my pubspec.yaml and I can't change much of those versions or the html editor advanced will  not work correctly.

this is when I addded embed youtube video and embed pdf :
[image]

but this is what shows up in my preview page ( on web ) , only text,images..etc :

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
export 'htmleditor_model.dart';
export 'htmleditor_model.dart';

class MyPreviewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String htmlText;

  const MyPreviewPage({Key? key, required this.htmlText}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

/*    if (kIsWeb) {
      return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Preview Page'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: HtmlWidget('$htmlText'),
        ),
      );
    } else {*/

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Preview Page'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child:  Html(
              data: htmlText,  
          ),
        ),
      )
      );
    }
  }
```

This is my pubspec.yaml , I can't change much of the versions because I'm using the html_editor_advanced and it seems to only work with these version :

```
name: text_editor_project
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: 3.0.0
  cached_network_image: 3.2.1
  flutter_animate: 1.0.0
  flutter_cache_manager: 3.3.0
  font_awesome_flutter: 10.1.0
  from_css_color: 2.0.0
  go_router: 3.1.0
  google_fonts: 3.0.1
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.5.1
  intl: 0.17.0
  json_path: 0.4.1
  page_transition: 2.0.4
  provider: 6.0.4
  shared_preferences: 2.0.15
  sqflite: 2.2.0+2
  timeago: 3.2.2
  url_launcher: 6.1.5
  firebase_core: ^2.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.6
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.4
  lottie: ^2.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.1
  google_sign_in_web: ^0.11.0+1
  flutter_windowmanager: ^0.2.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+1
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.0
  flutter_html: 3.0.0-alpha.5
  #sanitize_html: ^2.0.0
  #video_player_web: ^2.0.16
  #flutter_html_video: ^3.0.0-alpha.4
  #flutter_html_iframe: ^3.0.0-beta.2

dependency_overrides:
  provider: 6.0.0
  webview_flutter_android: 2.10.3
  webview_flutter_platform_interface: 1.9.5
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: 2.9.5

dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
    - assets/audios/
    - assets/lottie_animations/
    - assets/rive_animations/
    - assets/pdfs/
```

Comment: youtube and pdfs are just the typical example, I want to be able to use the embeded option in chrome browser, most of windows users are chrome oriented so that's why.
I'm looking for some dep that can handle flutter web html content and be able to show it. If you see the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html is only available for android and ios, shouldn't be an option for web too?

Comment: -_- I really think it a dependency version issue tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded the pubspec.yaml file and it worked and also downgraded some of the flutter_html one, turns out flutter_html_iframe is causing an issue.
Thanks to everyone who is trying to help & I hope this benefit anyone who got the same issue.

```
name: text_editor_project
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: 3.0.0
  cached_network_image: 3.2.1
  flutter_animate: 1.0.0
  flutter_cache_manager: 3.3.0
  font_awesome_flutter: 10.1.0
  from_css_color: 2.0.0
  go_router: 3.1.0
  google_fonts: 3.0.1
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.5.1
  intl: 0.17.0
  json_path: 0.4.1
  page_transition: 2.0.4
  provider: 6.0.4
  shared_preferences: 2.0.15
  sqflite: 2.2.0+2
  timeago: 3.2.2
  url_launcher: 6.1.5
  firebase_core: ^2.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.6
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.4
  lottie: ^2.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.1
  google_sign_in_web: ^0.11.0+1
  flutter_windowmanager: ^0.2.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+1
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  #flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.0
  universal_html: ^2.2.1
  flutter_html: ^2.1.2
  #sanitize_html: ^2.0.0
  #video_player_web: ^2.0.16
  #flutter_html_video: ^3.0.0-alpha.4
  #flutter_html_iframe: ^2.0.

dependency_overrides:
  provider: ^6.0.5
  webview_flutter_android: ^3.8.0
  webview_flutter_platform_interface: ^2.3.1
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^3.5.0

dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
    - assets/audios/
    - assets/lottie_animations/
    - assets/rive_animations/
    - assets/pdfs/
```